# Why AppCenter keeps saying "1 Update Available"?

Tags: appcenter

There aren't updates but next to "Operating System Updates" appears the button "Update" and if I click it nothing happens.

Comment: it's a bug, reported several times

Answer (score 1):

I already had this, did you try to make an update from the command line, usually it would disappear after

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it goes away after I reboot and "check updates" again.